# Wicket tables with empty data list

Tags: datatable, wicket

I am using Wicket DataTable to display a table. 
If the data list, which contains the data to be displayed inside the table, is empty then the table gets rendered with all the column headers and a label in the first row saying "No Records Found".

Is there any way to remove this label if the data list is empty and show only the column headers?

Answer (score 4):

The output is produced by the `NoRecordsToolbar`. It seems like you don't use a plain `DataTable` but a `DefaultDataTable` instead which adds the `NoRecordsToolbar` in its constructor.

You have (at least) three options:

- Create a new subclass of `DataTable` which doesn't add the `NoRecordsToolbar`.
- Set the resource key `datatable.no-records-found` to an empty value.
- Use the `DefaultDataTable` but remove the `NoRecordsToolbar`. Use `dataTable.getBottomToolbars().visitChildren(NoRecordsToolbar.class)` and remove it. That's not my favorite option because it seems a bit too brittle.

Comment: I created a subclass of DataTable, but its default behaviour is apparently to show the "no record found" message.
But you can set the visibility of NoRecordsFound, which works for me.